# custom flex component, visual controls in design view

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, flash-builder

Do you know how if you drag an `<mx:Label>` or `<s:Label>` component into your Flex project, when you go to design mode you get this panel on the right to set its properties like `text` etc.

I have a custom component that I can call with actionscript, or with mxml like this:

```
<comps:TheComp field1="OK" field2="Yes" />
```

The component takes this input and uses it for its internal operation

```
private var field1:String;
private var field2:String;

private function initializeit()
{
   // component takes the input and lays it out as needed
}
```

When I go to design mode, I can see the component under custom components, I can drag it to the stage and see it, but can't set its values `field1 and field` visually on the right like a normal `<s:Label>` or `<mx:Label>` would have.

Any idea how I can add that? Do I need to make it inherit something or anything else

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `[Inspectable]` metatag in your code

```
[Inspectable]
private var field1:String;

[Inspectable]
private var field2:String;
```

Not sure if inspectable members can be private. If [Inspectable] alone doesn't do it, try making the vars `public` or `protected`.

Comment: Without `[Inspectable]`, I can see them under `Properties | Category View` (the middle icon) but I was trying for a way to see them under `Properties | Standard View` (1st icon). The `Standard View` has properties related to `Style`, `Size and Position`, and `Layout`. Can the component set some of its properties to be listed there as well at the bottom for example?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put any custom components you want to view this way into a library project and make a swc out of it, then use the swc instead of just the source code http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/create-professional-flex-components/ .

HTH;

Amy

Answer (score 0):

Those variables must be public. Variables are accessible from properties panel after setting them public.

```
public var field1:String;
public var field2:String;
```